# How to use output of childprocess in called process without terminating child process?

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, tkinter, subprocess

I have created two modules in python. One of the module is for creating GUI using Tkinter and second one is for capturing and storing images.When I called opencv module in Tkinter module,it runs opencv module first and after releasing camera,it was running Tkinter module.So I used subprocess.Popen(). Now I want output of subprocess into Tkinter module. The code for creating GUI using Tkinter is as follows.

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import subprocess
def capcam():
    command="python2 imacap.py"
    subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)
root=Tk()
add=Frame(root)
add.grid()
root.title("Test")
capcam()
button_height=11
button_width=29
button_ipadx=2
button_ipady=2
text_box = Entry(add,justify=RIGHT,width=100, font=100)
text_box.grid(row = 0, column = 1,columnspan = 5)
text_box.insert(0, "0")
bttn_3 = Button(add, height= button_height ,width= button_width,text = "3")
bttn_3.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx=button_ipadx, pady=button_ipady)
```

Following is the code of child process.

```
import cv2.cv as cv
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
num = 0
while True:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.SaveImage('pic'+str(num)+'.jpg', img)
    if num == 500:
        del(capture)
        break
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
        break
    num += 1
```

I want the value of num variable at runtime in mainprocess and want to pass it to entry without terminating child process.

Comment: you don't need a subprocess here. You could use `threading` or `multiprocessing` to run the code from `imacap` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold a reference

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then you can do

```
num = int(p.stdout.readline()) # blocks!
```

if you do

```
print(num) in the child process
```

Also have a look at the module multiprocessing. It can solve the problem in other ways.

Comment: +1 for `stdout=PIPE`. To avoid blocking the GUI on `p.stdout.readline()`, you could [use `tk.createfilehandler()` or read in a background thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22118914/4279)

Answer (score 1):

[Can I have Tk events handled while waiting for I/O?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/gui.html#can-i-have-tk-events-handled-while-waiting-for-i-o) shows how to avoid blocking while reading a subprocess output from GUI thread. Assuming `imacap.py` has `print(num)` in it:

```
def read_output(self, pipe, mask):
    data = os.read(pipe.fileno(), 1 << 20)
    if not data: # eof
        root.deletefilehandler(proc.stdout)
    else:
        print("got: %r" % data)

proc = Popen(["python2", "imacap.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
root.createfilehandler(proc.stdout, READABLE, read_output)
```

The complete code example: [`tkinter-read-async-subprocess-output.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978) demonstrates  how to read the subprocess output without threads using Tkinter. It shows the output in the GUI and stops the subprocess on a button press.

If `tk.createfilehandler()` doesn't work on your system; you could try to use a background thread instead. See [`kill-process.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288) for the code example.

Comment: I did not even know that something like this existed. Totally cool. I guess you could even use sockets with that!

Comment: @User: it is a common feature for GUI frameworks e.g., `gtk` has [`io_add_watch()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15376317/4279), `qt` allows to specify [callbacks for QProcess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22110924/4279). `twisted`'s [`reactor.spawnProcess()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5750194) and `asyncio`'s (Python 3.4+) [`loop.subprocess_exec()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20697159/4279) also allow to read subprocess output asynchroniously in a portable manner.

Comment: And yes, sockets should be even more portable, you can even [mix sockets and subprocesses on some systems](https://gist.github.com/zed/7454768).