# Is there any option similar to expect_background in pexpect?

Tags: python, pexpect

I would like to know if similar/equivalent *expect_background* option is there in **pexpect**.

- Can some one let me know?

Comment: Please provide some more context.

Comment: HI....TCL expect_background runs continuously in the background, it matches every character that comes in. Please find the small description here: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/exploring-expect/9781565920903/ch19s06.html. I am trying to create tkinter terminal where I need to use this option, but havent found similar option in python. Basically, it matches everything on the console and sends it to GUI.

Comment: you could try: `root.createfilehandler(sys.stdin.fileno(), READABLE, your_callback)`. Here's [`createfilehandler()` helps to read output from a subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22118914/4279)